# menu jQuery e css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

O icone não esta ficando alinhado igual ao texto

Bom segue o código do menu, desde já agradeço a ajuda.

```js
$(".top_menu ul").each(function() {
  alignMenu(this);
  var robj = this;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(robj).append($($($(robj).children("li.hideshow")).children("ul")).html());
    $(robj).children("li.hideshow").remove();
    alignMenu(robj);
  });

  function alignMenu(obj) {
    var w = 0;
    var mw = $(obj).width() - 150;
    var i = -1;
    var menuhtml = '';
    jQuery.each($(obj).children(), function() {
      i++;
      w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      if (mw < w) {
        menuhtml += $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html();
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
    $(obj).append('<li class="hideshow">MAIS&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i><ul>' + menuhtml + '</ul></li>');
    $(obj).children("li.hideshow ul").css("top", $(obj).children("li.hideshow").outerHeight(true) + "px");

    // Abre o menu
    $(obj).children("li.hideshow").click(function() {
      $(this).find("ul").animate({
        height: 'toggle'
      }, 'fast');
    });
  }
});
$(".top_menu ul li").click(function() {

  // Verifica se tem link
  if (typeof $(this).data('link') !== 'undefined') {
    //document.location.href = $(this).data('link');
    console.log('link ok');
  }
});
```

```css
.material-icons {
  width: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.top_menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #616161;
}

ul.horizontal-menu,
.horizontal-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.horizontal-menu {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.horizontal-menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
  -moz-transition: border .218s;
  -o-transition: border-color .218s;
  transition: border-color .218s;
  background: #616161;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.horizontal-menu li .material-icons {
  margin: -10px;
}

.hideshow ul li {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.horizontal-menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(246, 83, 20);
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  background: #484848;
}

.horizontal-menu li.hideshow ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: -203px;
  width: 300px;
}

.horizontal-menu li.hideshow {
  position: relative;
}

.hideshow ul {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  background: #616161;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Inicializa o Jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top_menu">
  <ul class="horizontal-menu">
    <li>&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 1</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 2</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 3</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 4</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 5</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 6</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 7</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 8</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 9</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 10</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 11</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 12</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 13</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 14</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione a `class` `.search-icon` na primeira `li` da `ul`

```
<ul>
    <li class="search-icon"><i class="material-icons">search</i></li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 1</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 2</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 3</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 4</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 5</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 6</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 7</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 8</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 9</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 10</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 11</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 12</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 13</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 14</li>
</ul>
```

Depois adicione ao seu css.

```
.search-icon {
    padding: 22px;
}
```

Se for o que eu entendi tente fazer o seguinte:

```
<div class="top-fundo">
   <div class="container">
      <ul> ... </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

no css:

```
.container {
  width: 960px; /*defina o width*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: ok deu certo, agora fica faltando so o fundo, o `top_menu`. Sabe como resolver?

Comment: Como assim? explique mais pois não entendi.

Comment: Tenho uma div com a class `top_menu` ela tem que ser uma div com `width:100%` para criar uma barra em toda a página entendeu. Ela tem que ter a altura do menu. Entendeu?

Comment: olha a edição que fiz no post veja se ajuda.

Comment: Não deu certo. Bom olha a imagem de exemplo que montei http://i.imgur.com/hmud8Q8.png

Comment: @Guilerme Alves, editei a pergunta para explicar melhor os problemas. Se puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Deu certo? ou não?

Comment: deu certo sim, obrigado